# How to modify every value in unordered map in c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have a `unordered map` (umap) in C++ :

```
unordered_map<int, bool> dTimeResetUmap;
```

I am setting its value like:

```
dTimeResetUmap[person.object_id] = true;
```

`person.object_id` can be `0, 1, 2, 3` any int number. At certain point in code, I have to modify the al the values in it (basically have to make all the values as `false`) which I am doing like below:

```
int size_of_dTimeResetUmap = dTimeResetUmap.size();

for (int i = 0; i <= size_of_dTimeResetUmap; i++)
{
    dTimeResetUmap[i] = false;
}
```

But it seems not to be working for some value. After a long run of code, there are few values inside `dTimeResetUmap` which remains `true` instead of `false`. What can be the reason. Is it not a good way of updating values. Please help Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use C++ iterations to visit each element of map:

```cpp
for (auto & element : dTimeResetUmap)
{
    element.second = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use the indexing operator `[]` to access a value in the map, and the key isn't in the map, then a new key-value pair will be created, with a default "zero" value.

For a `bool` value, this "zero" will be equal to `false`.

So the simplest way to set all elements to `false` is to just [remove all elements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/clear) as then all access to the non-existing keys will create `false` values:

```
dTimeResetUmap.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use STL iterators;

```
for (auto it = umap.begin(); it != umap.end(); it++) {
  (*it).second = false;
}
```